# Правильное использование нескольких postMessage

Tags: c#

```
PostMessage(HWnd1, 0X000C, 0, str);
PostMessage(HWnd2, 245, 0, null);
```

HWnd1 и HWnd2 дочерные элементы одного и того же системного окна.

В этом случае Post №2 выполнится в любом случае позже Post №1 ?

Или возможно ситуация, когда второй выполнится раньше первого ?

PostMessage вроде как асинхронный метод.

Comment: я здесь наткнулся на линку, которая может быть важной относительно вопроса https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый найдёт нужное окно, поставит сообщение в его очередь сообщений, и вернется в место вызова.

Второй найдёт нужное окно, поставит сообщение в его очередь сообщений, и вернется в место вызова.

Поскольку номера сообщений не особенные (как, например WM_TIMER), они должны обрабатываться оконной процедурой приёмника в порядке поступления.

Однако гарантии обработки в том же порядке не документированы

Кроме того, если `str` - указательный параметр, его асинхронная передача может быть опасна даже в рамках одного процесса.

Comment: str - строка, вводимая в нужный элемент.
В вопросе уточнил по поводу HWnd1 и HWnd2. Это разные элементы одного и того же окна.

Comment: Вот вы послали локальную строку, сообщение в очереди болтается, после этого вышли из функции, и строка -  локальная переменная - освободилась. Сообщение наконец обрабатывается - а вместо строки мусор или вообще чужая память. Поэтому адреса передают синхронно, часть системных сообщений с адресами обрабатываются специальным образом под капотом. Про ваше (это WM_SETTEXT) - [лучше посылать синхронно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366175/postmessagehwnd-wm-settext-does-not-work-while-postmessagehwnd-wm-quit) (SendMessage)

Comment: Мне сказали, что через SendMessage не всегда сообщения доходят. Можно как то узнать, выполнен ли SendMessage после ого объявления ?

Comment: SendMessage возвращает результат, назначенный оконной функцией обработчика. Откуда вообще взялась необходимость в шарпе пользоваться сообщениями вместо простого назначения свойств?

Comment: в "ComboBoxEx32 / ComboBox / Edit " мне нужно строку определенную вписать.

Comment: SetWindowText имеете ввиду?

Comment: Окно, в которое посылается -  чужого процесса? SendMessage/SendMessageTimeOut всё же будет лучше использовать.

Comment: Да, Чужой процесс. Системное окно загрузки файла в браузер.

Comment: ОК, тогда про свойства не к месту. Сообщения посылать Send****